# Issue comparing doubles

Tags: java, comparison, mouse, collision

This simple if-comparison is not working, and i'm not sure why.

Code:

```
public abstract class Button extends Drawable_object {
...

@Override
public void update()
{
    super.update();
    mouseOver_last = mouseOver;

    double mx = Game_logic.get_mouse_x();
    double my = Game_logic.get_mouse_y();

    //the not working statement check:
    if ((mx <= x + ((double)width / 2))&&
       (mx >= x  - ((double)width / 2))&&
       (my >= y  - ((double)height / 2))&&
       (my <= y  + ((double)height / 2)))
    { mouseOver = true;}
    else mouseOver = false;
    ....
    }
```

Whilst Game_logic.get_mouse_x() and y are static methods:

```
public class Game_logic {
...

public static double get_mouse_x() { return mouse_x; }
public static double get_mouse_y() { return mouse_y; }
}
```

And those are set by Mouse adapaer in my main run class:

```
 public Board() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
 ...

 private class MAdapter2 extends MouseAdapter {
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        Game_logic.set_mouse_x(e.getX());
        Game_logic.set_mouse_y(e.getY());
    }

}
```

The thing is, when I draw on screen x - width / 2, mx and x + width / 2 (same with y), holding mouse at my desired position looks like statement must be true, but `mouseOver` is still false. How do i fix that?

Comment: Why not just use a MouseListener?

Comment: Have you tried printing your values to see what comes up? Also, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't answer your question directly, I am just showing that it is possible for your **if** statement to come out true. I believe you should print out **mx,my** and compare them to what you expect their value should be. This may be where your problem lies. Obviously you should also check your choice of **x,y,width,height**.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean mouseOver;
    int width = 50;
    int height = 50;
    double x = 40;
    double y = 40;
    double mx = 40;
    double my = 40;
    if ((mx <= x + ((double) width / 2)) && (mx >= x  - ((double) width / 2))
            && (my >= y  - ((double) height / 2)) 
            && (my <= y  + ((double) height / 2))) { 
        mouseOver = true;
    } else {
        mouseOver = false;
    }
    System.out.println(mouseOver);
}
```

Please print out all values for **mx,my,x,y,width,heigh** and post them and compare to what you thought they would be.

Comment: Hm, probably I didn`t express myself clear enough, but I do print out all those variables on screen. Here`s screenshot: [link](http://postimg.org/image/6fr8p00t1/)

Comment: Heh never mind, found out that this is caused by other problem, so probably I will create seperate thread for that.